# How to set background colour for header in TableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I found similar questions, but none of them helped me.
I need to set the background colour of headers in my table to white, it is gray now(same as background colour of the table).

Here are my `tableView` functions:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)
{
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 13)!
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blue
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, ViewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return tableView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
{
    return titles[section]
}
```

I'm setting background colour to white, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `viewForHeaderInSection` method of UItableview and Create UIview

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return headerView
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 15
}
```

Comment: i replaced my `viewForHeaderInSection` with yours(mine was mistyped btw), but it didn't help.

Comment: You should set heightForHeaderInSection of UITableview

Comment: added this function, still no effect

Comment: @Jamil Check Tableview Style, If is Grouped then you have to change as Plain in Storyboard

Comment: yes, it is grouped. i need distance between table sections, it is possible to do with plain?

Comment: yes, for that you have to specify heightForHeaderInSection

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3 - What did the trick for me was setting the header's **contentView**'s backgroundColor.

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "header") as? CollapsibleTableViewHeader ?? CollapsibleTableViewHeader(reuseIdentifier: "header")
            header.contentView.backgroundColor = .blueSteel
            return header
    }
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3, this worked for me:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let headerView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    headerView.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 13)!
    headerView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was actually the only answer that worked without using a custom View

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 below. One notable difference to previous answer, don't forget the override keyword. If you do, it won't override the function and will not work.

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        return headerView
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 15
    }
```